# Iterating through a map many times efficiently

Tags: java, collections

I have a cookie manager class that stores Lists of cookies by their domain in a Map. The size will stay below 100 most of the time.

```
Map<String, CookieList> cookieMap;
```

Every time I set up cookies for connections, it needs to iterate through all domains(`String`), check if it's acceptable, then insert the `CookieList`. I will be iterating through the map many times. I have a separate List holding the domains and search that, then get the `CookieList` by the Key.

```
List<String> domainList;

// host is from the connection being set up
for (String domain : domainList) {
    if (host.contains(domain)) {
        CookieList list = cookieMap.get(domain);
        // set up cookies
    }
}
```

Since I'm using `contains`, I can't directly get the Key from `cookieMap`. Is this a good way or should I just be iterating Map's EntrySet? If so, would LinkedHashMap be good in this example?

Comment: Iterating through 100 entries and doing a lookup in a map for each index is extremely fast. You probably don't need to optimize anything here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of maintaining a `Map` and a `List`, you could use `Map.keySet` to get the domains.

```
for (String domain : cookieMap.keySet()) {
    if (host.contains(domain)) {
        CookieList list = cookieMap.get(domain);
    }
}
```

There is nothing inefficient about this, since the for loop is O(n), and the call to cookieMap is O(1).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to loop `EntrySet` since Map.get(K) will search for the value, while `EntrySet` already has it?

Comment: Map.get(K) doesn't "search" for the value - the access time is constant, if you are using a HashMap implementation. Since the performance difference is beyond negligible, I think you should choose whichever way is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, CookieList>  coockieMap = new HashMap<String, CookieList>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, CookieList> entry : coockieMap.entrySet()) {
    if (host.contains(entry.getKey())) {
        CookieList list = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is pretty optimized, if you want, you can use

```
domainList.retainAll(hosts)
```

before your for loop, so stop doing a check every loop. Effetively, your code will look as follows :

```
List<String> hostList = new ArrayList<String>(domainList); // we don't want to edit domains

hostList.retainAll(host);  

for (String hostEntry : hostList) { // I'd rename "host" so I can use it here
        CookieList list = cookieMap.get(hostEntry);
        // set up cookies
}
```

Comment: I do like this idea because I will also need to check paths of cookie and url.